# how to calculate frequency of pairs in queryset

Tags: sql, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have two models in Django:

```
class Pair(models.Model):
   pass

class Person(models.Model):
    pair = models.ForeignKey(to=Pair, related_name='mates')
    city = models.ForeignKey(to=City)
```

So I need to calculate a frequency of pairs from different cities:

```
city_a<->city_b: 100
city_a<->city_a: 80
city_b<->city_c: 200
...
```

for each person I can get the other guy's city via:
`person.pair.mates.exclude(id=person.id).first()` or something like that so theoretically I can just loop through all instances of `Person` and then calculate the frequencies but apparantly that will be super inefficient.

but I can't figure out how to get this info via standard queryset (if there is a way). Any hints would be welcome

Comment: What is the number at the right? How do you calculate this?

Comment: Number of pairs where one person from city I and another from city J

Answer (score 3):

You can annotate the pairs, for example with:

```
from django.db.models import Count, F, Q

Person.objects.filter(
    Q(pair__mates__lt=F('pk')) | Q(pair__mates__gt=F('pk'))
).values(
    city1=F('city__name'),
    city2=F('pair__mates__city__name')
).annotate(
    number=Count('pk')
).order_by('city1', 'city2')
```

The `__name` should be a field of the city you want to use. For example `__pk` might be an option as well.

The query works as follows: the `Q(pair__mates__lt=F('pk')) | Q(pair__mates__gt=F('pk'))` normally should exclude "mates" that refer to the same `Person`. Then we use `.values(..)` to fetch the `name` (or other filed) from the city, and from the `pair__mates__city__names`. Now that we have these two values, we `Count(..)` the number of records per group of `city1` and `city2`. The `.order_by(..)` is necessary to avoid that subscripting, like `qs[1]` would return a single record from the original `Person` query.

The query thus looks like:

```
SELECT app_name_city.name AS city1,
       T5.name AS city2,
       COUNT(app_name_person.id) AS number
FROM app_name_person
INNER JOIN app_name_pair ON app_name_person.pair_id = app_name_pair.id
INNER JOIN app_name_person T3 ON app_name_pair.id = T3.pair_id
INNER JOIN app_name_city ON app_name_person.city_id = app_name_city.id
INNER JOIN app_name_city T5 ON T3.city_id = T5.id
WHERE T3.id < app_name_person.id OR T3.id > app_name_person.id
GROUP BY app_name_city.name, T5.name
ORDER BY city1 ASC, city2 ASC
```

This will return a `QuerySet` of dictionaries:

```
<QuerySet [
    {'city1': 'city_a', 'city2': 'city_a', 'number': 80},
    {'city1': 'city_a', 'city2': 'city_b', 'number': 100},
    {'city1': 'city_b', 'city2': 'city_c', 'number': 200}
]>
```

Comment: @PhilippChapkovski: the `~Q(pair__mates=F('pk'))` normally should exclude "mates" that refer to the same `Person`. Then we use `.values(..)` to fetch the `name` (or other filed) from the city, and from the `pair__mates__city__names`. Now that we have these two values, we `Count(..)` the number of records per group of `city1` and `city2`. The `.order_by(..)` is necessary to avoid that subscripting, like `qs[1]` would return a single record from the original `Person` query.

Comment: @PhilippChapkovski: for a queryset `qs`, you can print the query it will perform at the database side with `print(qs.query)`. So you can validate that it makes the query you aim to perform at the database side.

Comment: got it! Thanks a lot! The only part I didn't get is 'The .order_by(..) is necessary to avoid that subscripting, like qs[1] would return a single record from the original Person query.'

Comment: @PhilippChapkovski: well, unfortunately without the `.order_by()` if you use `qs[1]`, it will remove the `GROUP BY`, that is indeed rather "odd", it is a peculiarity of the Django ORM (and I hope that one day they will remove this peculiarity), but well for now, it is necessary to avoid this.

Comment: unfortunately, this part: `Person.objects.filter( ~Q(pair__mates=F('pk'))` results in `django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such column: U1.id`. The reverse one, without negation (`Person.objects.filter( Q(pair__mates=F('pk'))`) works fine, returning (unsurprisingly) all `Person` objects

Comment: what works like charm though (probably to update your answer: `filter(
    ~Q(pk__in=F('pair__mates'))
)`

Comment: @PhilippChapkovski: looks like there is some sort of bug in the Django ORM. Anyway, hopefully solved with a small edit, see update.